# Excluding routes using regex from verifying CSRF token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to exclude any routes starting from `admin` from verifying CSRF token.

This is how it declared in routes/web.php

```
Route::post('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::post('/admin/check', 'AdminController@check');
Route::post('/admin/test/{testId}', 'AdminController@test');
```

In `VerifyCsrfToken` I updated as following

```
protected $except = [
    'admin/*'
];
```

Which is not working, I'm getting `TokenMismatchException`

When I try like below it worked

```
protected $except = [
     'admin',
     'admin/check'
];
```

But adding `admin/test/{testId}` route in except is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Note - Using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
protected $except = [
    'admin', // for /admin route
    'admin/*' // for any sub path of /admin
];
```